What are the best, effective ways to help my teamates understand that moving the ball quickly is the most important?
I have a football team, and we play a 7-a-side game every week. I am not the coach, my team do not have a coach. We are just friends playing together. I could give advice to any teammate like a friend talking to a friend and they are likely to welcome that. The problem here is that they still don't understand the benefits of what I have told them.
Too many of my teammates choose to play the hard way.
Instead of:

passing the ball quickly with one or two touches,
keeping possession,
keeping the ball alive, and
avoiding unnecessary shots that result in a goal kick or losing the ball,

they prefer to:

keep the ball at their feet for too long,
attempt risky, "deadly" passes that are almost impossible to execute,
dribble excessively, often losing the ball or running it out of play, and
take too many shots, seemingly unwilling to maintain possession long enough to wait for a clear scoring opportunity. They are overly eager to shoot without considering the likelihood of success.

I wish they would play simpler. The intersting point is playing simpler is easier to do for everyone, but the results is more likely to be better with less effort. Playing with quick passes and maintaining possession is clearly easier and more effective, yet they consistently choose the harder approach.
How can I help them understand that playing simple passes, keeping possession, and avoiding low-percentage shots are crucial for improving our game? We are just an amateur football team, but I think if my team understand this, it is enough for us and we could win 80% of our low-level games.

Depends... do you have practice sessions or just the games?

"The intersting point is playing simpler is easier to do for everyone but the results is better. Playing with quick passes and maintaining possession is clearly easier and more effective" [citation needed]

@dly just the games, I am their friends, not their coach. I have told them several times but they quite don't get it

@PhilipKendall that is usually the case at low level football games.

@Dat to put my point more explicitly: why should your team believe what you say? How many teams have you actually coached with this style, and how much did you improve their results?

@PhilipKendall why? because that is the only viable option my team could try playing. I can not tell my teammates to improve their strength or skill. I am not a coach, I am a player on my team and my team have no coach.

What's your end goal? Winning? Just having fun? Clearly you aren't on the same page with your friends

@pboss3010 just having fun, but you know: losing isn't bringing so much fun

Is this 7-a-side game part of a league or just 14 friends meeting up and having fun?

@TheFootsie no league, just a game every week, each week we play against a different team. Normally, the players in a team know each other but don't know anyone in the other teams

While you're saying in comments "I'm not the coach", your actions are of someone who wants to be the (player) coach. Time to sit down with your team and see if they're happy for you to take that role. If they are, great. If they're not, that's their choice.

I don't have to be a coach to give my teammates some helpful styles of playing. My team is an amateur team and don't need an actual coach. We are friends playing together and help each other playing better. My teammates always welcome advices from other players, not just a coach. The problem here is they still don't understand the idea I want to convey to them. My question is how to do that, like a friend give advice to his friends. I strongly believe they choose to play the hard way because they have not seen the benefits of doing simple things which I have said to them several times.

I am not asking them to do those things. I want to help them understand first (how?). Once they understand, I believe they will do what I expected.
